# adview cause conflict in dependencies in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have started android like yesterday and i am creating a webview app. my app is working fine so i tried to add some google ads in it by using adview. there was a download icon in front of it. so i clicked on it where this dialog box came:

```
This operation requires the library com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.

Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:
-   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0@aar
and:
-   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0@aar

With the dependency:
-   androidx.annotation:*:1.1.0
versus:
-   androidx.annotation:*:2.0.0

The project may not compile after adding this library.
Would you like to add it anyway?
```

on clicking yes my app just start crashing, what ca i do to install adview without crashing my app....

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);


        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.reload).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.browser).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String host = "metv.ml";
                if (request.getUrl().getHost().toString().equals(host)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmetv.ml%2F&usg=AOvVaw1W5E2rKkshRXAYWJ-YahtX");

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                anim.setDuration(1000);
                findViewById(R.id.reload).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Start animating the image
                final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.reload);
                splash.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the `ads` version to 18.2.0

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```

or `downgrade` the annotation processor version of your project to :-

```
1.1.0
```